# Method not applicable?

Tags: processing

When I add the parameter "Color" to owl it says that the method owl is not applicable??
I want the owl to change into random colors any suggestions? This is an exercises from Reas and Fry's processing book.

```java
void setup ( ) {
  size(700,500);
  background(200);
  smooth( );
  frameRate(10);
}

void pick () {
  color (random(255),random(255),random(255));
}

void draw ( ) {
  owl(35,100);
}

void owl (int x, int y, color z) {

  pick ();

  stroke(0) ;

  strokeWeight(70) ;

  line(x, -35+y, x, -65+y) ;         // body

  noStroke() ;

  fill(255) ;

  ellipse(-17.5+x, -65+y, 35, 35) ; // left eye dome

  ellipse( 17.5+x, -65+y, 35, 35) ; // right eye dome

  arc(0+x, -65+y, 70, 70, 0, PI) ;

  fill(0) ;

  ellipse(-14+x, -65+y, 8, 8) ;      // left eye

  ellipse( 14+x, -65+y, 8, 8) ;      // right eye

  quad(0+x, -58+y, 4+x, -51+y, x, -44+y, -4+x, -51+y) ;  
}
```

Comment: This is not a javascript syntax....  you mean `function() setup() { .. } `?

Comment: processing is java based I believe

Comment: Then why is it tagged as javascript?

Comment: `void owl (int x, int y, color z) {` shouldn't that be `void owl (int x, int y, Color z) {`

Answer (score 2):

v.k. is actually right, although he did not tell you why the colour does not change. The problem is of course that you are calling owl with two parameters while it needs three. As far as I understand you want to pick the random colour with the `pick()` method, thus you don't need the third parameter in there.

```
void owl (int x, int y, color z) {
```

should be

```
void owl (int x, int y) {
```

Also you need to somehow fill (or stroke) things with the random colour you have correctly created. The problem is, as long as you don't pass it in a `fill()` or a `stroke()` method, it will not colour anything... So you need to have that colour somehow in the owl() method, you thus return it from the `pick()` command and use it like this:

```
color pick () {
  return color (random(255),random(255),random(255));
}
```

and you retrieve it in the owl method and store it in a variable so that you can use it:

```
color z = pick();
```

then to change the colour of the eyes you change

```
fill(0);
```

to:

```
fill(z);
```

Here's the final code in case I have confused you:

```
void setup ( ) {
  size(700,500);
  background(200);
  smooth( );
  frameRate(10);
}

color pick () {
  return color (random(255),random(255),random(255));
}

void draw ( ) {
  owl(35,100);
}

void owl (int x, int y) {
  color z = pick();
  stroke(0) ;
  strokeWeight(70) ;
  line(x, -35+y, x, -65+y) ;         // body
  noStroke() ;
  fill(255) ;
  ellipse(-17.5+x, -65+y, 35, 35) ; // left eye dome
  ellipse( 17.5+x, -65+y, 35, 35) ; // right eye dome
  arc(0+x, -65+y, 70, 70, 0, PI) ;
  fill(z) ;
  ellipse(-14+x, -65+y, 8, 8) ;      // left eye
  ellipse( 14+x, -65+y, 8, 8) ;      // right eye
  quad(0+x, -58+y, 4+x, -51+y, x, -44+y, -4+x, -51+y) ;  
}
```

Comment: thank you! I did something similar void owl (intx,inty,color z) {

Comment: yes :) I was just messing around and that seemed funnier to me :D evil owl!

Answer (score 1):

[`color`](http://processing.org/reference/color_datatype.html) is a Processing Datatype for colors. It is aware of `colorMode()`. The problem is simple, your own method is expecting 3 parameters `void owl (int x, int y, color z) {...` and you are calling it with 2 `owl(35,100)`. If you say:

`owl(35,100, color(random(255),random(255),)random(255));`

it will work.

Comment: I have already tried putting that parameter in as both "pick();" and the above both did not work

Comment: see @Petros Koutsolampros answer above :)